# Laravel Error: There is no existing directory at "/var/www/html/DocApp/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, error-handling

I have setup a 'DocApp' project by using `Laravel Framework` on `MAMP` on MAC machine. Project is physically located at

`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocApp`

I have run below command to make symbolic link of `storage` directory:

`php artisan storage:link`

It created symbolic `storage` folder in `public` directory.

I have started server services to run this project by below command in terminal:

`php artisan serve`

then opened project URL in the browser `http://127.0.0.1:8001/`

I am getting below error in the browser:

`There is no existing directory at "/var/www/html/DocApp/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied`

I have set `logs` folder permission to 777 and 755 but still getting the same error.

I have noticed a thing that correct project physical location is at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocApp` while error message is showing different location of this project `/var/www/html/DocApp/`

Please find the attached screenshot of error:

[image]

Kindly suggest me what is exact issue and how can we solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have deleted below cached files under `bootstrap` folder:

```
/bootstrap/cache/packages.php
/bootstrap/cache/services.php
/bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Then run `php artisan cache:clear` command in terminal.

And now everything is under control and working well, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Try running

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

give permission to your `storage` folder not only log folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Given permission to storage folder with recursively but still getting same issue. Any other suggestion, please share

Comment: @Kamlesh please check `logs` folder is exist or not in storage folder

Comment: already exists, 100% sure.

Comment: I have noticed a thing that correct project physical location is at `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocApp` while error message is showing different location of this project `/var/www/html/DocApp/` what is reason of this? Any suggestion, please share

Comment: please check if your project also exists in `/var/www/html/`

Comment: `/var/www/html/DocApp` open this in terminal & then give permission to storage folder.

Comment: I have double checked there is no file/folder at `/var/www/html` location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245480/discussion-between-natvarsinh-parmar-bapu-and-kamlesh).

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your '.env' file in root of your project.

```
WWWGROUP=1000
WWWUSER=1000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).